# Django: How to access database item from custom template tag

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to register a simple template tag that will return the percentage of a value by dividing the value within the template by a value stored in the database (total cost), currently I have the following template tag:

```
@register.filter()
def percentage(value):
    total_cost = Project.total_cost
    return value / total_cost * 100
```

in this case, 'Project' is the field name defined in the project. However, how does Django know which 'total cost' is the relevant one? Is this the best way to go about solving this issue?

Comment: the easiest way is to pass total_cost as argument to the function like `def percentage(value,total_cost)` and process that.

Comment: This will work however it won't dynamically change for different projects or if the total_cost entity changes, is there a way to go about this by fetching the total_cost from the database?